# Посоветуйте учебник по Python

Tags: python, книги

Здравствуйте, огромная просьба помочь мне с выбором учебника по Python. Уровень знаний о программировании на Python по 10-ти бальной шкале где- то в районе 0.5 .

И еще, может пока не поздно попробовать начать изучение C ?

Comment: Да, кстати... Забыл сказать, что учить я начал Python 3.2

Answer (score 5):

На мой взгляд, лучшая на данный момент книга по python **Изучаем Python, 4-е издание, Марк Лутц**.

Comment: Спасибо! Вспомню буквы и начну читать.

Comment: Насчёт Лутца двоякое впечатление если честно. С одной стороны книга неплохая, но слишком она перегружена материалом повторяющимся. Т.е. одно и тоже автор слишком много раз повторяет повторяет повторяет. Её можно легко сжать.. :)

Comment: @G71: «Повторяет» — это Зед Шоу с его «Learn Python the Hard Way», на фоне этого книжка Лутца — сама ненавязчивость. Хотя LPTHW — хорошая книга. Но специфичная.

Answer (score 1):

Программирование на Python 3. Подробное руководство
Python. Подробный справочник

Если осилишь то будет неплохой уровень знаний.

Comment: Думается мне сложновата она будет для уровня знаний 0,5

Comment: Если ты про сишечку, то она не сложновата она бесполезна.
А книги да сложные, но понятные.

Comment: Не, я про книгу. Программирование на Python 3 я бы читал сразу после Лутца.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Итак. Вы советуете мне сначала познакомиться с трудами Лутца, а затем перейти к прочтению вышеописанных книг?

Comment: Да, вполне хорошая подборка выйдет. Ну и привыкай писать на двух версиях параллельно.

Comment: Ага, а я думал, что если я научился писать на Пайтон 2.0 (чисто гипотетически), а затем вышел Пайтон 3.0, то та версия, что я изучил устарела и надо переходить на 3.0

Comment: Всем спасибо! Пошел читать...

Comment: Пайтон 2 нескоро еще устареет, а жаль. Хотя 2.7 уже несильно отличается от 3.x, что радует.

Answer (score 1):

обязательно читайте помимо книг python.org Т.е. вместе с книгами постоянно ходите по этому сайту и разбирайтесь со стандартной библиотекой

Answer (score 0):

Здесь несколько онлайн [учебников о python](http://pep8.ru/doc/) на русском языке.

Тут [видео-уроки](http://pep8.ru/video/)

Тут большая подборка [статей о python](http://pep8.ru/blog/)

Answer (score -1):

Так же могу посоветовать труды Н.А. Прохоренок. Я заказывал с озона (мне просто тяжело воспринимать информацию с экрана монитора). Очень хорошо построена, а справочник в конце заменит любой гугл.

Comment: Ага хорошая книга... чтоб научиться говнокодить на таком прекрасном языке. А справка в конце просто чудо, какая-то "Python. Подробный справочник" и в подметки не годиться.

Comment: Не вижу поводов для ненависти с вашей стороны. Все книги нацелены на разный уровень. Конкретно книга этого автора помогла мне освоить азы. Я стараюсь изучать и дополнительную литературу, и различные форумы и блоги вроде этого.

Comment: Такие книги изначально приучают к написанию плохого кода. Так зачем такое надо если есть много хороших проверенных временем книг?

Извиняюсь если чем-то вас обидел.

Answer (score -2):

вот еще часть документации по Python 2.6 на русском языке [https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python/Учебник_Python_2.6](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_Python_2.6)

Comment: Спасибо. Полезно.

Comment: Неактуально. Учите английский господа.

Answer (score -2):

Если для вашей работы понадобится C++/C#, то учите. Учить сам C нужно, если в ваших целях он стоит, или идете на работу, где он нужен. Ну или просто для самообразования.
Про питон- книги самоучители, или для начинающих, раз у вас нет опыта в программировании.